# How to verify Paypal webhook signature in PHP?

Tags: php, ssl, paypal, openssl, webhooks

I'm not very knowledgeable in SSL and certificates. I used the post 
"[How to use hash_hmac() with "SHA256withRSA" on PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30162771/how-to-use-hash-hmac-with-sha256withrsa-on-php)" to see if I can get webhooks with PayPal working.

The issue I am have is I am getting the following error after calling `openssl_verify()` and a return result of (0):

> OpenSSL error openssl_verify error:04091068:rsa routines:INT_RSA_VERIFY:bad signature

I've tried to solve this, but documentation on errors and the functions around the web is minimal to none.

My current code looks like this:

```
 // get the header post to my php file by PayPal
 $headers = apache_request_headers();
 // get the body post to me php file by PayPal
 $body = @file_get_contents('php://input');
 $json = json_decode($body);

 // TransmissionId|TransmissionTimeStamp|WebhookId|CRC32 as per PayPal documentation
 $sigString = $headers['Paypal-Transmission-Id'].'|'.$headers['Paypal-Transmission-Time'].'|'.$json->id.'|'.crc32($body);

 // $headers['Paypal-Cert-Url'] contains the "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE---MIIHmjCCBoKgAwIBAgIQDB8 ... -----END CERTIFICATE-----"
 $pubKey = openssl_pkey_get_public(file_get_contents($headers['Paypal-Cert-Url']));

 // and this is the call to verify that returns result (0)
 $verifyResult = openssl_verify($sigString, base64_decode($headers['Paypal-Transmission-Sig']), $pubKey, 'sha256WithRSAEncryption');
```

Only different from the reference code I used, is that I do not use `openssl_pkey_get_details($pubKey)` because I will get below error in addition to the existing signature error:

> OpenSSL error openssl_verify error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
>   OpenSSL error openssl_verify error:04091068:rsa routines:INT_RSA_VERIFY:bad signature

Also I've tried a variation by not using `base64_decode()` on the header but that would get the same return result (0) with error stating:

> OpenSSL error openssl_verify error:04091077:rsa routines:INT_RSA_VERIFY:wrong signature length

What is wrong with the signature?

Comment: I believe you should not use `$json->id` because this is the ID of the event, not the ID of the web hook. The web hook ID is not sent with the event - you have to use a constant here.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use this piece of code:

```
$pubKey = openssl_pkey_get_public(file_get_contents($headers['PAYPAL-CERT-URL']));
$details = openssl_pkey_get_details($pubKey);

$verifyResult = openssl_verify($sigString, base64_decode($headers['PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-SIG']), $details['key'], 'sha256WithRSAEncryption');

if ($verifyResult === 0) {
    throw new Exception('signature incorrect');
} elseif ($verifyResult === -1) {
    throw new Exception('error checking signature');
}
```

Comment: I guess @Maxime Rainville's suggested solution with an official SDK is a bit better idea. Even though you'll need to do another HTTP call for that.

Answer (score 2):

The formula is `<transmissionId>|<timeStamp>|<webhookId>|<crc32>` not `<transmissionId>|<timeStamp>|<eventId>|<crc32>`. Also note that Webhook simulator events can't be verified.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you were looking for, but an alternative to manually validating the signature with Open SSL could be to use the PayPal PHP Restful API.

The PayPal Restful API exposes an endpoint that allows you to validate webhook: [/v1/notifications/verify-webhook-signature](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/webhooks/#verify-webhook-signature)

The [PayPal-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK) provides a `VerifyWebhookSignature` class that make it easy to make calls to that end point.

They also have a [Sample Script](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/notifications/ValidateWebhookEvent.php) illustrating how to use `VerifyWebhookSignature` class.

Answer (score 0):

As @JUBEI mentioned, you need to get the WEBHOOK_ID from your PayPal account and **NOT** from the headers you've received, remember the first time you've registered the webhook event, you must find your webhook ID right there.

Plus, make sure to use `OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256` instead of: `'sha256WithRSAEncryption'`, refer to: https://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.signature-algos.php

[image]